# WPF DataGrid with textbox in template column not firing property changed

Tags: wpf, validation, datagrid, propertychanged

I have a datagrid with a template column, and in that template is a textbox.  It's bound to the 'Quantity' property of the object in the collection that makes up itemssource.  Quantity is an integer.  When I add an item to the datagrid, I am adding an event handler to the PropertyChanged event of the item:

```
EnteredPart.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(p_PropertyChanged);
```

This works fine when the user enters an integer in the textbox... the p_PropertyChanged handler fires and I can disable buttons and alter quantities as necessary.  When the user enters a non-integer, the handler doesn't get called, I just get a red outline around the textbox.  Because of this, I can't disable the necessary buttons when I need to (they should be disabled with the quantity is not legit.)  Is there any way that I can do something about this?

**EDIT:**  I tried changing the Quantity property to a string, and this caused the property changed handler to be called when non-integral values are entered.  However, I then added validation to the textbox to check for this, and if the Validate method returns false, the property changed handler once again ceases to be hit.  Is there any way at all to get both validation and property changed notifications??

**EDIT 2:**  Here another instance of this problem I'm having, in another location.  I have a form for adding/editing phone numbers.  The phone number textbox looks like this:

```
  <TextBox >
       <TextBox.Text>
           <Binding Path="Phone.Number">
               <Binding.ValidationRules>
                   <local:PhoneValidationRule />
               </Binding.ValidationRules>
           </Binding>
       </TextBox.Text>
   </TextBox>
```

Upon clicking a save button, I need to check in my viewmodel if the number is valid, because if it's not, I don't want to run the save command.  However, it doesn't seem as if there's any way to do that, because if the validation fails, then the Phone.Number property has a null value, and I have no way to check to see if I should run the save command.  I either need access to the error state (which I thought would work by Validation.GetErrors, but doesn't), or to the actual text within the textbox, which isn't available in the viewmodel.

Comment: Is your `ItemsSource` an `ObservableCollection` ? If you want to use `PropertyChanged` in a `DataGrid` you need to bind to a collection implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged`, ie. for example `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Yes it's an observablecollection.  As I said, the property changed handler fires correctly when an integer is entered.  When I enter a non-int into a textbox bound to an integer property, it just doesn't fire.  The validation error template appears, but the "quantity" property doesn't change.

Comment: Well, I'd say this is a totally normal behavior. You're trying to put a non-int in an int field. If the validation fails, the property won't change, it will be set only if the validation allows it!

Comment: So then probably the only way to make it work like this is to implement IDataErrorInfo, right?  How annoying.

Comment: I can't really understand your problem here. Validation rules are defined for this exact aim: they prevent you to update the model with bad data (ie. they won't let you fire any PropertyChanged if you're not allowed to change the property). Why exactly do you need this PropertyChanged to be fired?

Comment: I don't necessarily need it to be fired if there's a simpler way.  I need to change some messages and disable some buttons and tab items if there are invalid entries.

Comment: Edited to try to clarify the problem a bit.

Comment: I think here you are just being confused by the validation roles. As you saw, ValidationRules are meant to prevent invalid data to be entered. However when you run the save command, you can add a validation rule here as well so it won't be launched if you have null somewhere. Otherwise you can implement `IDataErrorInfo` and check on that before running your save command

Comment: That was what I assumed earlier; IDataErrorInfo.  I just don't like having my data validation in the model, but I don't see a better way at this point, in terms of mvvm WPF.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check my answer, tried to add some clarifications about `IDataErrorInfo` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, validation in the View part has many drawbacks if you are in an MVVM architecture.

You'd try here to check your model's content, in the view: you'd therefore break MVVM's architecture by calling your model in the view.

Using `IDataErrorInfo` will help you to fulfill MVVM's main objective (ie. clearly separate the three parts).

Just an example:

I think here you are just performing a very small validation (just check if it is an int or not).
But in a different environment, assume that your model is much more complicated and needs a deeper validation. Using `IDataErrorInfo` will help you to check deeply in your model without calling it from the view.
As a matter of fact, in my personal experience, as I regularly work with large and highly correlated datasets, I cannot even picture using validation without `IDataErrorInfo` because it'd cost me too much to investigate in all the data presented and find potential errors

Comment: I suppose you're right.  What annoys me about WPF is that I feel as if everything I do is so overwrought... because it takes an extra 45 minutes' worth of coding to do anything.  Just to check for 'text is int and greater than 0' involves implementing an interface, wiring up binding changes in the XAML code, and adding checking logic to the viewmodel.  Last year I would've added a textbox.text check in the codebehind and finished in under 10 minutes.  It feels like backwards movement.  Perhaps the real issue is that WPF with MVVM wasn't the right choice for my application, I don't know.

Comment: As long as I know, I always had a feeling about WPF: it usually makes the extraordinary difficult things VERY EASY, and the very simple things VERY TRICKY. For example, the DataGrid is just awesome, it is so easier to work with a bound List and letting WPF take care of all the displaying process! However just as you said, I had some very trivial problems and ended up spending one full day solving them... And sometimes I see people implementing an incredible amount of code for very basic operations (ie. a common problem: implementing an AttachedBehavior for... a MouseDoubleClick. Kill me.)

Comment: Maybe I'm being a little unfair to WPF... perhaps it's the MVVM pattern at fault.  In my case, for example, nothing in WPF stops me from adding the checks I needed in codebehind.  It's the MVVM pattern which breaks if I do this.  It just reinforces my idea that a huge percentage of design patterns are a waste of time, and 'time' is really what it all boils down to.  I simply don't believe that the amount of time this _might_ save me in maintenance can come close to the amount of time it's costing me in development.  Not even close.

Comment: Well, I'd argue there that you may be wrong. The only thing forbidden in MVVM is to handle data operations in code-behind. Thanks to Bindings, you can just handle them in the ViewModel, just as easily as if it was in code-behind. Therefore it is often as easy as the classical code-behind approach, and moreover it is much more clear (I recently had to re-create a full GUI... took me 30minutes to make it work.) When it comes to refactoring, I seriously think that there is no better handling than MVVM, helping you to refactor only the part needed without impacting other parts

Comment: I see what you're saying about the code-behind, but my point was that if I want to validate something in code-behind, it's useless unless I also do something in the viewmodel.  It's not the end of the world, but it's definitely not as easy.  I would certainly argue that it's much less clear, and I honestly don't see how MVVM refactoring is any better than old n-tier refactoring.  I don't think I've ever had a problem modifying object oriented code which was split into tiers.  I feel as if I'm trying to fix something which was never broke, just for the sake of using new "design patterns".